# In C, returning a float when sending pointer-to-struct values to a function changes the values of the struct

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I am trying to get some practice using structs and pointer-to-structs in the C language.  I ran into an issue that has stumped me.  I have set up a function that takes in 3 values from a pointer-to-struct and returns a float.  However, when calling this function, it modifies the values of the original struct, eventually leading to an access violation and some nasty character regurgitation.  After stepping through the code, the values are fine until I return the value of the function.

This is my struct:

```
struct product
{
    int ID;
    char name[MAXNAME];
    char department[MAXDEPT];
    float price;
    int taxable;
    int free_shipping_eligible;
};
typedef struct product Product;
```

Function prototypes:

```
Product * getInput(void);
float transactionTotal(const float price, const int taxable,
const int free_shipping);
void displayTransaction(const Product * inventory,
const float total_price);
```

Main:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Declare a pointer to a struct.
    Product * invPoint = NULL;
    float grand_total = 0.0;

    // Get the value of the address of a struct.
    invPoint = getInput();

    // Use that address to get the total of a transaction.
    grand_total = transactionTotal(invPoint->price, invPoint->taxable,
        invPoint->free_shipping_eligible);

    // Display product information and the transaction's total.
    displayTransaction(invPoint, grand_total);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the function that fills the values of a member of the struct:

```
Product * getInput(void)
{
    // Declare our struct and struct pointer variables.
    Product inventory;
    Product * fillInventory = NULL;

    // Get user input.
    printf("Please enter the product's ID.\n\t");
    scanf("%d", &inventory.ID);
    printf("Please enter the product's name.\n\t");
    scanf("%s", &inventory.name);
    printf("Please enter the product's price.\n\t");
    scanf("%f", &inventory.price);
    printf("Which department is the product located in?\n\t");
    scanf("%s", &inventory.department);
    printf("Is it taxable?  0 for no, 1 for yes.\n\t");
    scanf("%d", &inventory.taxable);
    printf("Is it free shipping eligible?  1 for no, 0 for yes.\n\t");
    scanf("%d", &inventory.free_shipping_eligible);
    fillInventory = &inventory;

    // Return a pointer to our struct.
    return fillInventory;
}
```

The transactionTotal function seems to be the culprit.  Here is its code:

```
float transactionTotal(const float price, const int taxable,
const int free_shipping)
{
    float total_price = 0.00;
    float tax = (float)(taxable * TAX_RATE);
    float shipping = (float)(free_shipping * SHIPPING_RATE);
    total_price = price + price * tax + price * shipping;
    return total_price;
}
```

Before starting the above functions, I entered the following values:

ID: 232

name: "Coffee"

department: "Food"

price: 8.99

taxable: 0

free_shipping_eligible: 1

After the transactionTotal function:

ID: -858993460

name: (strange characters)

department: (strange characters)

price: 9.88899994

taxable: -858993460

free_shipping_eligible: 14679252

Comment: Your `getInput` function returns the address of `inventory`, even though it no longer exists when the function returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    // Return a pointer to our struct.
    return fillInventory;
}
```

Your structure object is declared in your function and has a lifetime that ends after your function returns. The structure object is discarded when your function returns and trying to access it afterwards invokes undefined behavior. Pass your structure object as a parameter to the function or use `malloc` to allocate its storage in order to fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `getInput`:

```
Product inventory;
Product * fillInventory = NULL;
....
fillInventory = &inventory;

// Return a pointer to our struct.
return fillInventory;
```

You're returning the address of a local variable.  When the function returns, that variable goes out of scope, resulting in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to dynamically allocate space for this struct.

```
Product * getInput(void)
{
    Product * fillInventory = malloc(sizeof Product);
    ...
```

Then the caller needs to `free` that struct:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Declare a pointer to a struct.
    Product * invPoint = NULL;
    float grand_total = 0.0;

    // Get the value of the address of a struct.
    invPoint = getInput();

    // Use that address to get the total of a transaction.
    grand_total = transactionTotal(invPoint->price, invPoint->taxable,
        invPoint->free_shipping_eligible);

    // Display product information and the transaction's total.
    displayTransaction(invPoint, grand_total);
    free(invPoint);         // free the memory
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `invPoint` could just be a struct living throughout the lifetime of `main()`. It would be totally adequate and avoid the `malloc()`/`free()` calls.